# iphone load table with wcf

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, nsurlconnection

atm i can successfully loading data from a WFC, read the json and put it on the right objects.

But my problem comes when i need to show a table with this data, cuz i don't know where to play the method or when should i call it. Atm looks like the table is created and after that i get the data from the web. Should i reload the table or can i get the info before the class calls cellForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Is there a way to make a connection synchronic and not synchronic? because in this case, if i cant get the list of eventos form wfc its has not point showing a table. So

Thx in advance!

my code:

```
-(id)init{
//call superclass designated inizialzer
self= [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
if(self){

    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Eventos"];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];   
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/..."]];

    [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]autorelease];   


}
return self;
 }
```

about connection:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
[responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
 [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
//  label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {      


NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];


NSError *error;
SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
NSDictionary *luckyNumbers = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];

[responseString release];   

if (luckyNumbers == nil)
  //        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"JSON parsing failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
    [luckyNumbers release];
else {      


    for (NSDictionary *object in [luckyNumbers objectForKey:@"EResult"]) {
        Evento *e=[[Evento alloc] init];
        e.nombre= [object objectForKey:@"nombre"];
        e._id= (int)[object objectForKey:@"id"];
        e.fecha= [object objectForKey:@"fecha"];
        [[EventoStore defaultStore]addEvento:e];
        [e release];
    }

}
}
```

about the table it self:

```
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [[[EventoStore defaultStore] allEventos]count];
 }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

//check for reusable cell first and use it
UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
//if there is no reusable cell, we create one
if(!cell){
    cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                  reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"]autorelease];
}
Evento *e=[[[EventoStore defaultStore] allEventos] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[[cell textLabel] setText:[e nombre]];

return cell;

}

 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *) aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPax{
LotesViewController *loteViewController= [[[LotesViewController alloc]init]autorelease];

NSArray *eventos=[[EventoStore defaultStore]allEventos];
[loteViewController setEvento: [eventos objectAtIndex:[indexPax row]]];
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:loteViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should reload the table after getting the data. you can show the activity indicator on the table till you get the data and once you get the data, you can remove the activity indicator and reload the table. this way you can find the solution to your problem. No need to go for synchronous connection. Just add the activity indicator once the connection is satrted and remove it when data comes.

Comment: this is lazy load right?? i dont know what is this activity indicator u are telling me. can u modify my code or point me where can i read about it?